# Getting output from GUI application to Excel and providing input to GUI application from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, gui, application-launch

Is there any way to interact from Excel with an separate GUI application?
I need to provide few numbers as strings to the text fields of said GUI application, and then read an output from that same application from other text field, switch tabs on that GUI app and possibly starting it.

Comment: Have you looked at VBA? Does your other tool offer an API connection?

Comment: No and no. Can it be done without API connection in VBA?

Comment: Yes, but not very easily. You'd need to use screen scraping. There is an example in here https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?392874-Screen-Scraping-Windows-Applications but as you can see it's not straightforward.

Comment: You might develop (or find)  a COM add-in to do that:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-com-add-ins-and-automation-add-ins-91f5ff06-0c9c-b98e-06e9-3657964eec72 That said, this would need to be customized, likely beyond the scope of this forum.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik can a COM add-in interact with external app? From what I've read it's excel only, no?

Comment: Com " is used to enable inter-process communication." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model